# Performing calculation from two mysql tables by month

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have two tables, one income and one for expenses

Income

```
id date                  amount person_id
1  2015-08-03 00:00:00   100    1
2  2015-09-03 13:32:10   200    2
```

Expenses

```
id date                  amount person_id
1  2015-09-03 13:32:43   12     1
2  2015-08-03 13:32:56   20     2
3  2015-08-03 13:35:55   17     2
4  2015-09-03 13:36:20   12     2
```

What I would like to do in mysql is to calculate by month the balance of each person from the income minus expenses.

MY SQL statement

```
SELECT
e.person_id,
Concat(MonthName(e.date), " ", Year(e.date)) AS Month,
SUM(e.amount) AS "Total Expenses",
SUM(i.amount) AS "Total Income",
SUM(i.amount)- SUM(e.amount) AS "Balance"
FROM
a_expenses e
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
a_income i ON e.person_id=i.person_id
 GROUP BY e.amount, e.person_id, Month(e.date)
```

RESULT

```
person_id Month           Total Expenses Total Income Balance
1         September 2015  12             100          88
2         September 2015  12             200          188
2         August 2015     17             200          183
2         August 2015     20             200          180
```

How do I set the constraint that the income is calculated based on the sum for the month for each person and the result only show the person once for each month.

Comment: Remove `e.amount` from `group by` clause.

Comment: Removing e.amount will make the Total Income double for the month of August  

    "person_id","Month","Total Expenses","Total Income","Balance"
    "1","September 2015","12","100","88"
    "2","August 2015","37","400","363"
    "2","September 2015","12","200","188"

Comment: Then what's your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You make the assumption that the expense table has values for every month or that there are no months in the income table not also in the expense table. You cannot guarantee those conditions will always exist (IMHO)

To avoid this you need to involve a table that lists the people, something like this:

```
SELECT
      p.id
    , p.name
    , Concat(MonthName(COALESCE(e.mnth, i.mnth)), " ", YEAR(COALESCE(e.yr, i.yr))) AS Month
    , SUM(COALESCE(e.expense_amount,0)) AS "Total Expenses"
    , SUM(COALESCE(i.income_amount,0)) AS "Total Income"
    , SUM(COALESCE(i.income_amount,0) - COALESCE(e.expense_amount,0)) AS "Balance"
FROM persons p
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  person_id
                , MONTH(date) AS mnth
                , YEAR(date) AS yr
                , SUM(amount) AS expense_amount
            FROM expenses
            GROUP BY person_id
                   , MONTH(date)
                   , YEAR(date)
      ) e ON p.id = e.person_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  person_id
                , MONTH(date) AS mnth
                , YEAR(date) AS yr
                , SUM(amount) AS income_amount
            FROM income 
            GROUP BY person_id
                   , MONTH(date)
                   , YEAR(date)
      ) i ON p.id = i.person_id and e.mnth = i.mnth and e.yr = i.yr
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I"m looking for and completely unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT
e.person_id,
e.Month,
SUM(e.amount) AS "Total Expenses",
SUM(i.amount) AS "Total Income",
SUM(i.amount)- SUM(e.amount) AS "Balance"
FROM
a_income i
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select sum(amount) as amount,person_id,Concat(MonthName(date), " ",
Year(i.date)) as Month from a_expenses group by person_id, Month(date)) 
 as  e ON e.person_id=i.person_id
 GROUP BY e.person_id, e.Month
```

Check with example SqlFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3d4e/18

Comment: Thank you. I got the gist of the SQL query I have to build.